# How do I trigger an update event to a winform which changes images (showing traffic)?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two static classes, UDP Connection and TCP connection. They both trigger use two static methods from the Traffic Observer class called TrafficObserver.DataSendingActive() and TrafficObserver.DataSendingInactive(). These methods will get hit when either UDP or TCP class sends data. I have a form that has two image indicators for transmit and recieve (tx rx). The indicators should change from gray to green when either of the connections classes are actively sending. How do I trigger an event in my form to carry this out?

Example

**TCPConnection**

```
try 
{
  TrafficObserver.dataSendingActive();
  tcpStreamWrite(data);
  TrafficObserver.dataSendingInactive();
}
```

[image]

**Question:** How do I hook up an event listener correctly with these static classes? Would I write a global event?

Comment: can you not create a `Event or a MultiCast Delegate`? also it would help I think if you would show what the 3 additional Classes look like nice diagram / drawing btw.. but code always works better

Comment: I'm free to do whatever I would like as long as I make it happen

Comment: I will post a simple example on what you could try

Answer (score 0):

For one of the classes you could do something like this to get you started

```
private bool _traffic;
public event System.EventHandler TrafficDataChanged;

protected virtual void OnTrafficChanged()
{ 
     if (TrafficDataChanged != null) TrafficDataChanged(this,EventArgs.Empty); 
}

public bool Traffic
{
    get
    {
         return _traffic;
    }

    set
    {
         _traffic=value;
         OnTrafficChanged();
    }
 }
```

Comment: change to `TrafficObserver` in the EventHandler if needed